# process.env variable undefined on test using Jest in Azure function(Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, azure, jestjs, azure-functions

`process.env` variable showing undefined while running `yarn run jest`. I have stored every config variables in my `local.settings.json` file, and it is working perfectly in normal debug.

My code is like this:

`local.settings.json`:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Host":  {
                 "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
                 "CORS": "*"
             },
    "Values":  {
                   "IOTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING":  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                   "AZURE_DEVOPS_URL":  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
               }
}
```

`jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  log: jest.fn(),
}
```

azure httptrigger function - `index.js`:

```
const iothubConnectionString = process.env["IOTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING"];
console.log( iothubConnectionString ) //undefined
```

My tests fail due to these configuration variables. I need to pass the test. anyone can you please help me.

Comment: Please don't use images to share your code. Edit your question and include the code directly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`local.settings.json` is specific to Azure Functions Core Tools. As long as you use Core Tools CLI to run the function you can access environment variables defined in this file via process.env

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pragna, If I hard coded the  process.env variable value, my test become pass. then why because the test failed if I am  using process.env as a variable?